# How to block Bluestacks from accessing the internet?

Tags: windows, bluestacks

I want to block Bluestacks on Windows from accessing the internet.

I tried blocking the main app `Bluestacks.exe` in the Windows Firewall but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct application to block in the firewall is `C:\Program Files\BlueStacks\HD-Player.exe`

Comment: very good idea, thank you !